# ERR_SERVER_ALREADY_LISTENING error with Node.JS app but only with 10.2.1?

Tags: node.js, sockets, server, version, listen

I have a Node.JS app running on Ubuntu Linux 18.04 (Bionic).  It runs fine on Node.JS version 8.11.1; no errors at all.  But when I try to run it with 10.2.1, I get the following error the instant I execute the *listen()* method on the server I create:

```
    net.js:1416
        throw new ERR_SERVER_ALREADY_LISTEN();
        ^

    Error [ERR_SERVER_ALREADY_LISTEN]: Listen method has been called more than once without closing.
        at Server.listen (net.js:1416:11)
        at Object.<anonymous> (./web-site/bin/www:56:8)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:14)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:10)
        at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:238:19)
        at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:572:3)
    Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

I triple-checked this but I am only calling the *listen()* method once.  Besides, if that was really the problem, the code wouldn't work with older versions of Node.JS.

Can anyone think of why this is happening and how I might fix it?

Here is the code for my *bin/www* file.  This is the file that is launched in my debug configuration when I run the app:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Web start file that supports SSL and listens for traffic on port 7300.
 */

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('aux:server');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.  If not, use port 3000.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create the HTTPS server.
 */

var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

// Get the location of the private key and fullchain files for SSL support
//  from the environment.
var privkeyPath = process.env.PRIVKEY_PATH;
var fullchainPath = process.env.FULLCHAIN_PATH;

// Validate them.
if (!fs.existsSync(privkeyPath))
    throw new Error("Invalid private key file path: " + privkeyPath);

if (!fs.existsSync(fullchainPath))
    throw new Error("Invalid fullchain file path: " + fullchainPath);

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(privkeyPath),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(fullchainPath),
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: true
};

var server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Certificate enabled express server listening on port " + port);
});


/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
    var port = parseInt(val, 10);

    if (isNaN(port)) {
        // named pipe
        return val;
    }

    if (port >= 0) {
        // port number
        return port;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
    if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
        throw error;
    }

    var bind = typeof port === 'string'
        ? 'Pipe ' + port
        : 'Port ' + port;

    // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
    switch (error.code) {
        case 'EACCES':
            console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        case 'EADDRINUSE':
            console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        default:

        throw error;
    }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
    var addr = server.address();
    var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
        ? 'pipe ' + addr
        : 'port ' + addr.port;

    debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Summary

This error happened to me when doing unit testing with Fastify and chai-http. I was trying to execute `chai.request()` before the server had finished starting.

#### Full explanation:

At the top of the test, I have:

```
const server = require('../server');
```

And in `server.js` is the code to start the server and connect to the database.

```
const fastify = require('fastify')(opts);
fastify.register(require('./routes'));

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await startServer();
  } catch (err) {
    logErrors(err);
  }
};
start();

module.exports = fastify.server;
```

When I then tried to do the following unit test:

```
describe('Test', () => {
  it('should respond with 404', async () => {
    let res = await chai.request(server).get('/invalid-url');
    expect(res).to.have.status(404);
  });
});
```

I get the error:

> Error [ERR_SERVER_ALREADY_LISTEN]: Listen method has been called more than once without closing.

The problem is that starting the server and connecting to the database is asynchronous, but the unit test is being run synchronously.

#### The fix:

I'm not sure if there is a better way to get around this, but this is how I solved it. In my `server.js` file I changed it to:

```
let starting = false;
let started = false;

// Start the server!
fastify.server.start = async () => {
  try {
    await waitForStartInProgressToFinish();
    if (!started) {
      await startServer(); // This sets starting and started accordingly
    }
  } catch (err) {
    logErrors(err);
  }
};

async function waitForStartInProgressToFinish() {
  let waitCount = 0;
  while (starting === true && waitCount < 400) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5));
    waitCount++;
  }
}
```

Then in my unit test code, I add the following `before()` hook:

```
describe('Test', () => {
  // ... Tests

  before(async () => {
    await server.start();
  });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Check that:

You must use  the `.listen()` method only one time; just comment the line `server.listen(port);`

```
var server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Certificate enabled express server listening on port " + port);
});

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.listen('listening', onListening);
```

Comment: Link only answers are not useful for future readers in case of the link being expired or the content is down. So add the relevant details from the source over here in your original answer.